# Getting two 2nd order equations from two 1st order equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Context: two-state Landau-Zener transition problem in physics.

I am trying to uncouple the following two 1st order equations ($c_0$ and $c_1$ are time dependent)

\begin{eqnarray}
i \dot{c_0} &=& a t c_0 - f c_1 \\
i \dot{c_1} &=& -a t c_1 - f c_0 \\
\end{eqnarray}

into the following uncoupled 2nd order equations (for just c_1 for example)

$$
\ddot{c_1} + [f^2 - i a + (at)^2]c_1 =0
$$

My first attempt was to try to just differentiate both equations again, and plug those two resulting equations into Solve in mathematica for the quantities $\ddot{c_0} $ and $\ddot{c_1}$ but this is not fruitful.

Am I missing something much more obvious about how to uncouple these equations?

Thank you

Comment: Rewrite the _second_ equation to $c_0 = -(i\dot c_1+atc_1)/f$. Differentiate _that_ once and plug the resulting expressions for $c_0$ and $\dot c_0$ into the _first_ equation. Simplify.

Comment: Wow. super brain fart :/ Thank you :) feel free to submit that as an answer for some points hhaha :)